# Why is $\{x-y: x,y\in K,\ d(x,y)\geq 1/n\}$ a compact set in a metrizable topological space with compact $K$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

> Assume that $K$ is a compact convex set in a Hausdorff locally convex space, and $K$ is metrizable with the induced topology. Let $d$ be a metric defining the induced topology. Show that the set
>   $$
> C_n=\{x-y: x,y\in K,\ d(x,y)\geq 1/n\}
> $$
>   is compact.

---

[Motivation:]I come up with this question when reading a proof of the following proposition

> Assume that $K$ is a compact convex set in a Hausdorff locally convex space, and $K$ is metrizable with the induced topology. There exists a continuous function $u$ on $K$ which is strictly convex, i.e.,
>   $$
> u\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)<\frac{u(x)+u(y)}{2}
> $$
>   for any $x,y\in K$ with $x\not=y$.

The following is the proof:

> First observe that any function $u$ of the form $u(x)=|\varphi(x)|^2$, with $\varphi\in X^*$, is convex (show that $u$ is continuous and mid-point convex). Moreover, for such a function we have
>   $$
> u\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)<\frac{u(x)+u(y)}{2}
> $$
>   provided that  $\varphi(x)\not=\varphi(y)$. The desired function will be constructed as
>   $$
> u(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\varphi_n(x)|^2,\quad x\in K
> $$
>   where the functionals $\varphi_n$ are chosen so as to
>
> - separate the points of $K$ and
> - $|\varphi_n(x)|\leq 1/n$ for $x\in K$.
>
> It will suffice to show that for every $n\geq 1$ there exists a finite set $F_n\subset X^*$ such that, for $x,y\in K$ with $d(x,y)\geq 1/n$, there exists $\psi\in F_n$ with $\psi(x)\not=\psi(y)$.
>
> $\color{red}{\textrm{Indeed, observe that the compact set}}$
>   $$\color{red}{
> C_n=\{x-y: x,y\in K,\ d(x,y)\geq 1/n\}}
> $$
>   does not contain the origin, hence $V_n\cap C_n=\emptyset$ for some absolutely convex neighborhood $V_n$ of zero.
>
> Choose a finite set $A_n\subset C_n$ so that $A_n+V_n\supset C_n$, and for every $x\in A_n$ choose a functional $\psi_x$ such that $\Re\psi_x(x)>\Re_x(v)$ for all $v\in V_n$. The set $F_n=\{\psi_x: x\in A_n\}$ satisfies our requirements.

Comment: Isn't any closed subset of a compact space compact? $C_n$ is the inverse image of the closed set $[\frac1n,\infty)$ under the map from $K\times K$ (which is itself compact) to $\Bbb R__+$ sending $(x,y)$ to $d(x,y)$ (which is continuous since the metric defines the topology).

Comment: @GregMartin, I think the closed set you are talking about is $S=\{(x,y)\in K\times K\mid d(x,y)\geq1/n\}$, which is indeed the pre-image of $[1/n,\infty)$ under $d:K\times K\to\mathbb{R}$. But $C_n=f(S)$ where $f:K\times K\to K$ is $f(x,y)=x-y$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jack then you're done too because $f$ is continuous and so maps compact to compact sets.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, ah, indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, it suffices to note that the set 
$$
S=\{(x,y)\in K\times K\mid d(x,y)\geq 1/n\}
$$
is closed (and thus compact in $K\times K$), and 
$$
C_n=f(S)
$$ 
with $f(x,y)=x-y$ which is a continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_m,y_m)\in K\times K$ be such that $d(x_m,y_m)\geq 1/n$ and $x_m-y_m\to z$ in metric. By compactness of $K\times K$, there exists convergent subsequence
$$
(x_{m_k},y_{m_k})\to (x,y)
$$
for some $(x,y)\in K$. By continuity of the function $f(x,y)=x-y$, 
$$
x_{m_k}-y_{m_k}\to x-y.
$$
Thus $x-y=z$. Note also that 
$$
d(x,y)=\lim_{k\to \infty} d(x_{m_k},y_{m_k})\geq 1/n.
$$
It follows that $z=x-y\in C_n$. Now we can conclude that $C_n$ is closed in $K$.